# MongoDB append to an array of an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongoDB document looks like this

```
name:"XYZ"
P: Array
   0: Array
      0:1604647764553
      1:0
```

I want to make it look like this

```
name:"XYZ"
P: Array
   0: Array
      0:1604647764553
      1:0
      2:"NEW Value"
```

Using `updateOne({name: "XYZ"},{'$push': {[P:"NEW Value"}}})` ads the value to P and it becomes like this

```
name:"XYZ"
P: Array
   0: Array
      0:1604647764553
      1:0
   1:"NEW Value"
```

Which is not what I want. Can someone please help me... how do I specify an element of an array in updateOne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append `"NEW Value"` to the first element of P array, then you can use the following query:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  name: "XYZ"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "P.0": "NEW Value"
  }
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AiQkkjrs2kU)